# Nested and independent GIT repos, for Backup, how?

Tags: git, nested, backup

I want to use GIT as a Backup solution. 
I have a windows shared network in my Company and a Centos Server.
Each user have a unique shared folder, where is located all files of user. We have 2 developers, they can have a git repo(s).

How Can I make the entire folder of user a GIT repo, a perform usual git operations, commit, push, etc, without import if subfolders have git repos?

Note: Submodules is not a solution, I don't know what repositories is under the main folder of user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why Git does not make a good backup solution:

- you cannot have nested Git repositories -- there is no way to coerce Git to treat a nested `.git` directory like a normal directory
- it doesn't save complete permissions and ownership
- its index format does not scale to many files
- it does not handle large files well (it runs out of memory because it needs to put the entire file in memory to compress -- or at least that was true about a year ago, maybe they've fixed it)
- while the compression is good for source code, it's not very good for virtual machine images, etc.
- backing up to a remote system involves backing up locally first
- no defense against backup file corruption

That being said, there are some reasons why Git would be awesome as a backup solution:

- every backup is a complete snapshot -- you don't need to restore an old full backup followed by some number of incremental backups in order to get the latest files
- ridiculously good deduplication performance
- good space efficiency in general
- great support for efficiently transferring backups to remote systems

My recommendation:  take a look at [bup](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup/).  It's not very mature, it's not seeing much active development, and it lacks some important features, but it has a lot of promise.  It's an open source backup program based on Git.  They've kept the things Git does well, but replaced/augmented some of the things Git does poorly (for backups).

Comment: "backing up to a remote system involves backing up locally first": Not really. I can to allocate the .git directory in a folder outside user directory.  git --git-dir=../repo --work-tree=. add .

"no defense against backup file corruption". An example about this problem and solutions implemented by others system backups?

Comment: I'm trying to test BUP, but the documentation is too poor. I have only:
bup help
Usage: bup [-?|--help] [-d BUP_DIR] [--debug] [--profile] <command> [options...]

Common commands:
    fsck       Check backup sets for damage and add redundancy information
    ftp        Browse backup sets using an ftp-like client
    fuse       Mount your backup sets as a filesystem
    help       Print detailed help for the given command
    index      Create or display the index of files to back up ...




Do you know a WIKI or what is the common work flow of BUP for incremental Backups?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is

```
git init
```

at the base of each users. If they are storing their git repos there, the scope of git will stop at those directories that have a `.git` folder.

It's not clear if what you want to do is to commit the git repos to another git repo. I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: I want that Git treat a nested .git directory like a normal directory. For backup propurses.

Comment: I don't have write rights to create a .git dir in the backup directory of users. I'm trying to use some as: git --git-dir=../repo --work-tree=. add foo