# Nested Repository. Git. Change working directory

Tags: git

**What I have**
I have  a Git Repository inside another.
Like

```
Repo1/
     .git
      fileOfRepo1
      Repo2/
          .git
           fileofRepo2
```

I have done some commit in repo1 and repo2.

**HERE is the problem**
When doing checkout to a previous commit of repo1 I would like to have my files change to those of the previous commit. That happens for the files of the Repo1 it doesnt for those of Repo2.

It DOES however recognize that something happened here is how I know that

If I am in the last commit of Repo1 on branch master I obtain

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

*However after I do*

$git checkout SHA

*I obtain*

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Repo2 (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If I were using submodules I will type : git submodule update and I will get the desired behaviur,but I DO NO want to use submodules. SERIOUSLY no submodules advice please. Can i be more clear NO SUBMODULES.

I am using a local repository is just to organize my own projects.

Comment: Is git subtree out, too? Why do you need nested repositories? If for backup purposes, see [Nested and independent GIT repos, for Backup, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269804/nested-and-independent-git-repos-for-backup-how). If for software development, consider using a build system that installs dependencies from git repositories outside your source tree if necessary, instead of nesting their repo into yours.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that git ignores sub folders which are git repos on their own. So it doesn't recurse down to the child repo, so that state won't change when you checkout a different version in the parent repo, resulting it in not getting the version of the child associated with the parent.